# Is the limit of this sequence of function $1$ or $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, sequence-of-function

I was given to compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)$ with $x\in(0,1)$, where 
$$f^n(x)=\begin{cases}
0\,\,& x\leq0\\
x\,\,& 0<x<1/n\\
1\,\,& x\geq1/n
\end{cases}.$$

Would the answer simply be $1$? Because 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=\begin{cases}
0\,\,& x\leq0\\
1\,\,& x>0
\end{cases}$$
and given that $x\in(0,1)$ then we pick $1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: The $f^n$ (rather than $f_n$) is *very* confusing. This suggests either powers or $n$-fold composition of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\le 0$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$.

If $x>0$, then $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n$ such that $n\ge \frac{1}{x}.$

Therefore your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify your work a little. From the first step, since $x\in(0,1),x>0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n} = 0$, $\exists N$ st $\forall \epsilon >0, \dfrac{1}{n}<\epsilon\Rightarrow$ $x>\dfrac{1}{n}$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=\begin{cases}
x\,\,& 0<x<1/n\\
1\,\,& 1/n<x<1
\end{cases}$$

we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=1$$

indeed $\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists n_0>0\quad \forall n>n_0$$

$$|f^n(x)-1|<\epsilon$$

indeed it suffices to take $\frac1{n_0}<x \implies n_0\ge \frac1x$.

Answer (score 0):

I depends what you mean by convergence. This is an example that shows that the set of continuous functions is not closed in the $L^2$ sense.